# Contour integration over a spiral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma} (z^2-2) \mathrm{d}z$$ where $\gamma$ is the following curve:
>
> [image]
>
> Use two methods: direct calculation via a parametrization of $\gamma$, and the fundamental theorem.

I know about the fundamental theorem, so I simply evaluate $\frac{z^3}{3}-2z$ at $3$ and $0$, the end points of the curve. My problem is that I don't know how to parametrize spirals such as this for the second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to let the radius vary with the angle, so try something like $\gamma(t) = cte^{it}$, and let's find $c$. We have $\gamma(0) = 0$, and I want $\gamma(6\pi) = 3,$ so: $$6c\pi e^{6i\pi} = 3 \implies 6c\pi = 3 \implies c = \frac{1}{2\pi}.$$

I took $6 \pi$ because of the drawing. We are going counterclockwise and we went around three times. We could use the same line of thought for $c_1te^{ic_2t}$, but I didn't see how changing the speed could help us. Try $\gamma(t) = \frac{t}{2\pi}e^{it}$, then.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will try this and if I can find a contour integral calculator, I'll compare the answers.

Comment: Seeing again, isn't it easier to just evaluate $\frac{z^3}{3}-2z$ directly? You know that the endpoints are $0$ and $3$. So the answer would be just $3$..

Comment: Yes, of course. I will use that as a check for your method, but I should have mentioned that we are supposed to use two methods (as a demonstration of the fundamental theorem, I assume).

Comment: @Ducky, I made you a little drawing, check the edit in my answer. I think it will work just nice.

Comment: very nice, thank you. So in general, it seems one might parametrize a spiral which starts at $0$ and ends at $x$ by $\gamma(t)=\frac{t}{2 \pi} \cos(t)+ it \sin(t)=\frac{t}{2 \pi} e^{it}$.

Comment: Yes, the process is the same, write $\gamma(t) = cte^{it}$, pick the point where the curve ends, evaluate and solve for $c$.